# NullPointerException at String array in Adapter constructor in Android

Tags: android

I want to check the equality of image file path name . When run the app , the application crash and getting error in Constructor in Adapter class at for loop sentence is =   **for(int n = 0; n <= mStringArray.length; n++)** in My Adapter Class.

Here is my ImageAdapter class Consrtuctor

```
  public ImageAdapter(Context c, String[] fpath) {
            context = c;
            filepath = fpath;

            TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.MyGallery);
            itemBackground = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
            a.recycle();

            if (newFolder.isDirectory()) {
                listFile = newFolder.listFiles();

                filepath = new String[listFile.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++)
                {
                    filepath[i] = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();
                    Log.e(" filepath[i] " , " = " +  filepath[i]);
                }

                for(int m = 0 ; m <= filepath.length; m++)
                {
                    String firstValue= filepath[m];
                    Log.e("Image is ","firstValue = " + firstValue);

                    for(int n = 0; n <= mStringArray.length; n++)
                    {
                        String SecondValue = mStringArray[n];
                        Log.e("Image is ","Secondvalue = " + SecondValue);

                        if(firstValue.equalsIgnoreCase(SecondValue))
                        {
                            Log.e("Image is ","Equal");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.e("Image is ","Not Equal");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is my Sqlite Query method

```
 public List<String> getAll_ImageAudioPath() {
        labels = new ArrayList<String>();

        dbhelper = new MyDbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from ActivityObjectList where activityId ='" + strDescription + "'", null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                labels.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("imageaudioPath")));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        int strLabelSize = labels.size();
        Log.e("Value of strLabelSize ", " = " + strLabelSize);

        for (int i = 0; i < labels.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("Value of element ", " = " + i + " & " + labels.get(i));
            strLablepath = labels.get(i);
            Log.e("Value of strLablepath ", " = " + strLablepath);

            mStringArray = new String[labels.size()];
            mStringArray = labels.toArray(mStringArray);

            for(int x = 0; x < mStringArray.length ; x++){
                Log.e("mStringArray[i]  is","" + mStringArray[i]);
            }  
}
```

Can someone help me how to compare the two String Array with image path in Image Adapter.Thanks to appreciate.

Comment: in the for loop just remove `=` from `m <= filepath.length;` and try

Comment: show the log for npe

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting the `NullPointerException` on this exact line

```
for(int n = 0; n <= mStringArray.length; n++)
```

then it can only be because `mStringArray` is `null` when you reach the loop. A `NullPointerException` results from dereferencing a `null` reference; that is, trying to access a field or method of something that's `null`. The only place on this line that you dereference anything is in the `mStringArray.length` expression, and this will give you an NPE if and only if `mStringArray` is `null`. It's not possible to verify this from the code you gave, though, because we can't see any other references to `mStringArray`.

The others' comments are probably right that you intended `n < mStringArray.length` rather than `<=`, but this won't result in a NPE in any case. It would be more likely to give an `IndexArrayOutOfBoundsException`, but in the *body* of the loop, not in the `for` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
       for(int m = 0 ; m < filepath.length; m++)
            {
                String firstValue= filepath[m];
                Log.e("Image is ","firstValue = " + firstValue);

                for(int n = 0; n < mStringArray.length; n++)
                {
                    String SecondValue = mStringArray[n];
                    Log.e("Image is ","Secondvalue = " + SecondValue);

                    if(firstValue.equalsIgnoreCase(SecondValue))
                    {
                        Log.e("Image is ","Equal");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.e("Image is ","Not Equal");
                    }
               }
        }
```